# Truncate items at end of HStack

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking to truncate and hide items at the end of a HStack if there is not enough space for them.

E.g.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Lorem")
            Text("ipsum")
            Text("dolor")
            Text("sit")
            Text("amet")
            Text("consectetur")
            Text("adipiscing")
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 100))
    }
}
```

This produces:

[image: Produced View]

Instead of this I want to keep all of the items in the VStack at their ideal width. But when we run out of space I want to truncate the next and then hide the rest.

E.g. Truncate "consectetur" and hide "adipiscing"

[image: Wanted View]

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach is to use layout priority, and separate data from view to make this simpler.

Here is simplified demo. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
let data = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing"]
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) {
            Text(data[$0])
               .layoutPriority(-Double($0))    // << here !!
        }
    }
    .lineLimit(1)  // << here !!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asperi's answer is robust and easily maintainable. I would recommend going that way unless your requirement for a display of the number of omitted texts is fundamental to your app. If that is the case then you might want to consider the following, much more brittle, solution.

*Caveat No. 1:*
I’m told that SwiftUI expects size information to flow **downward** from the parent View to the child View. All constructs that run counter to this expectation can become problematic, including the code below!

*Caveat No 2:*
I did not solve all the issues of how padding around HStacks and spacing between HStack-elements affect the HStackWithTruncation. Running out of time I tossed in a property  called `gratuitousSpacing`.   Currently the logic seems to be working with gratuitousSpacing set to zero, but there have been a few troublesome hiccups. My apologies for the bugs.

*Caveat No. 3:*
I wasn’t sure what you meant by ‘Tags’ being added to HStacks. Instead of Tags I just used SwiftUI Text Views.

**TL;DR**

The size of the Text Views needed by the parent View comes from sources outside of the parent. As such, the size data needs to be treated as part of the parent View’s state. The problem with state is that **every change** to a View's state causes the View to update itself. An infinite loop arises in which the parent View calls the child View to draw itself, which causes the child to report the size of a text field, updating the state of the parent, which then redraws itself, again calling the child, again updating the text size (and so on). You have to prevent this infinite loop from occurring, which can be awkward.

In the logic below the main rule is that you only report the size of a Text View the **first time** you encounter the text that is displayed in the Text View. The parent will still call to the child to redraw itself multiple times, but it will be a finite loop.

Overview:

1. Figure out how to size a single Text View
2. Use an invisible ZStack to get an array of Text View sizes
3. Create a HStackWithTruncation that contains the invisibleZStack
4. Demo the use of this View in ContentView

**ScreenShot**

(The gray rectangle is used to squeeze or expand the space available to HStackWithTruncation)
[image]

*Caveat The Last:*
I suspect that this could all be simplified using an @ObservableObject class where we would have tighter control of when to publish the size of Text Views. Unfortunately, adding an ObservableObject to  code that uses preferenceKeys causes mystery compiler errors to appear throughout the known universe. It might actually be the cause of global warming. I gave up. If you have better luck please let us know!

**1. Sizing A Single View**

As you’ve shown, PreferenceKeys can be used to report the size of a child View to its parent. I used the module below just because it’s familiar to me. I got it from a tutorial on the [FiveStars blog](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/) (which might be useful to folks not familiar with these keys):

`````
import SwiftUI

/// creates a preference key allowing a Child View to report its size to its parent View
///
///  This is somewhat awkward to use, so it is encapsulated in an extension to View
///  as a `.readSize` View modifier.  See below.
struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey
{
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    
    /**
     this function is called by a child View to report its size to a parent View.
     
     - Parameter onChange: a closure you provide that uses the $0 parameter to capture the size of a child view
     - Returns: some View

     Example:
     ````
        var sizeOfChildView: CGSize = .zero
     
        var body: some View {
            Text("This is the text that will be measured")
                .readSize { newSize in
                    sizeOfChildView = newSize
                }
        }
    */
    public func readSize( onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View
    {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference( key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
                                 value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange( SizePreferenceKey.self,
                             perform: onChange)
    }
}
`````

**2 Get the width of  all the Text Views (Tags)**

The above code is then used in an invisible Z-Stack that contains all the
Text Views that need to be sized. Its real job of this struct is to build an array of Text View widths.  Here is the code in a module that builds that array, including a preview that displays the resulting array-of-widths.

```
import SwiftUI

/**
 creates a hidden View to hold Text Views and builds a bound-array containing the sizes of each
 
 The sizes for each Text View include an allowance for the spacing used by HStack
*/
struct HiddenZStackForSizing: View {
    
    // MARK: input
    var textForDisplay: [ String ]
    var spacingUsedByHStack: Double
    var font: Font = .body
    
    // MARK: returned values & body
    @Binding var allWidths: [ Double ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(
                Array( zip( textForDisplay.indices,
                            textForDisplay ) ),
                id: \.0 )
            {   index, text in
                // The allWidths bound variable is part of the
                // parent Views state. Updating this array will
                // cause the parent view to re-draw itself, 
                // inducing HiddenZStackForSizing to be re-drawn
                // as well. To avoid an infinite loop, only update
                //  allWidths IF this is the first time that 
                // this 'text' element has been seen. 
                if index == allWidths.count {
                    Text( textForDisplay[ index ] )
                        .font( font )
                        .readSize { newSize in
                            let totalSize =
                            newSize.width + spacingUsedByHStack
                            allWidths.append( totalSize )
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .hidden()
    }
}

// MARK: - Preview
struct HiddenZStackForSizing_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestHiddenZStackForSizing()
    }
}

// show that HiddenZStackForSizing produces a list of sizes
struct TestHiddenZStackForSizing: View {
    let textForDisplay =
    [ "Alphonse", "Bartholomew", "Catherine",
      "Dostoefsky", "Elwood", "Frank" ]
    @State private var allWidths = [ Double ]()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    ZStack {
                        HiddenZStackForSizing(
                            textForDisplay: textForDisplay,
                            spacingUsedByHStack: 4.0,
                            allWidths: self.$allWidths)
                        Text( String(describing: self.allWidths) )
                    }
                Spacer()
                Text("Count of widths: '\( allWidths.count )'")
                Spacer()
            }
            }
    }
}
```

**3 Build HStackWithTruncation**

The following module places an instance  HiddenZStackForSizing in a view so that a sibling HStack knows which Texts should be omitted. A preview is included that shows such a truncated HStack.

```
import SwiftUI

/**
 an HStack with that appends child views until the summed width of the child Views exceeds the width allocated to the HStack
 */
struct HStackWithTruncation: View {
    
    // MARK: input
    var textForDisplay: [ String ]
    var paddingToOmittedTextView: Double
    var gratuitousSpacing: CGFloat
    var hStackSpacingForTexts = CGFloat( 4.0 )
    
    // MARK: returned values
    @Binding var countOfOmittedTexts: Int
    
    // MARK: state & body
    @State private var currentChildViewWidths = [ Double ]()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                /*  hidden View used to return the sizes of the Text Views. */
                HiddenZStackForSizing(
                    textForDisplay: textForDisplay,
                    spacingUsedByHStack: hStackSpacingForTexts,
                    allWidths: $currentChildViewWidths )
            
            // Contains the HStack showing only a limited number
            // of texts
                let allowedText =
                getAllowedTexts(
                    proxy: geo )
                HStack( spacing: hStackSpacingForTexts ) {
                    ForEach( allowedText, id: \.self ) { text in
                        Text( text )
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal )
        }
    }
}

// MARK: convenience functions
extension HStackWithTruncation {
    
    /**
     returns the earliest entries in textForDisplay having a total width that does not extend beyond the HStack's natural width.
     */
    private func getAllowedTexts( proxy: GeometryProxy )
                                -> [ String ]
    {
        var summedWidth =
            paddingToOmittedTextView + gratuitousSpacing
        let maxWidth = CGFloat( proxy.size.width )
        
        // get array of all text-widths that fit within the HStack
        let widthsAllowedAsSummed =
            currentChildViewWidths.filter
            {   width in
                summedWidth += width
                return summedWidth < maxWidth
            }
        // for each of the allowed text-widths, map the corresponding text
        let allowedText =
            widthsAllowedAsSummed.indices.map
            { index in
                return textForDisplay[ index ]
            }
        
        // update the number of omitted Text elements
        countOfOmittedTexts =
            textForDisplay.count - allowedText.count
        
        return allowedText
    }
}

// MARK: - preview
struct HStackWithTruncation_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        TestHStackWithTruncation()
    }
}

struct TestHStackWithTruncation: View {
    
    let textForDisplay =
        [
            "alpha",
            "bravo",
            "charlie",
            "delta",
            "echo",
            "foxtrot",
            "golf",
            "hotel",
            "india",
            "juliette",
            "kilo",
            "lima",
        ]
    let paddingToOmitted = 0.0
    let gratuitousSpacing = 20.0
    @State var countOmittedText = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack( spacing: paddingToOmitted ) {
            HStackWithTruncation(
                textForDisplay: textForDisplay,
                paddingToOmittedTextView: paddingToOmitted,
                gratuitousSpacing: gratuitousSpacing,
                countOfOmittedTexts: $countOmittedText )
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity )
            Text( "+\( countOmittedText )" )
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity )
        }
        .padding()
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

**4. Demo with ContentView**

The following module shows how to use the HStackWithTrunction. It’s meant to be the opening View in an app. If you would like to vary the space available to the HStackWithTruncation the code has a Color.gray instance where you can expand or contract the width, which squeezes or expands the width available to HStackWithTrunction

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let textForDisplay =
        [
            "alpha",
            "bravo",
            "charlie",
            "delta",
            "echo",
            "foxtrot",
            "golf",
            "hotel",
            "india",
            "juliette",
            "kilo",
            "lima",
        ]
    @State private var countOfOmittedText = 0
    let hStackSpacingToOmittedText = CGFloat( 0.0 )
    let gratuitousSpacingFactor = CGFloat( 0 )
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            Text( "Using:" )
                .font( .title )
            Text( "\( String(describing: textForDisplay ) )" )
            Spacer()
            
            Text( "Truncated HStack")
                .font( .title )
            HStack {
                // gray Color View used to vary the available width
                Color.gray
                    .frame( width: 100 )
                    .frame( maxHeight: .infinity)
                // ** HStack with truncated sub-HStack and Omitted-Count **
                HStack( spacing: hStackSpacingToOmittedText )
                {
                    HStackWithTruncation(
                        textForDisplay: textForDisplay,
                        paddingToOmittedTextView: hStackSpacingToOmittedText,
                        gratuitousSpacing: gratuitousSpacingFactor,
                        countOfOmittedTexts: $countOfOmittedText )
                    .frame( maxHeight: .infinity)
                    
                    // omitted text count
                    Text("+\( countOfOmittedText )")
                        .frame( maxHeight: .infinity )
                }
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true )
            .padding( .horizontal )
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the only way for you, you can make a string of you want to show like in this way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .frame(width: 300)
    }
}
```